# ASP Classic VB if condition not working

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

i just work with an IF OR operator on asp classic using vb, but it seems not working correctly as i expected. I need if which one of the VALUES(VALUE1 or VALUE2) have a value not 0, or both have (for example) 1 value it will works.

```
set rsY = cn.execute ("SELECT COUNT(VALUE1) AS VALUE1, COUNT(VALUE2) AS VALUE2 FROM DUAL")
VALUE1= "1"
VALUE2= "0"
if not rsY.eof then 
        VALUE1= rsY("VALUE1") 
        VALUE2= rsY("VALUE2")
    end if 
    set rsY = nothing


if (Cint(VALUE1) = 0) or (Cint(VALUE2) = 0) then
'code should here
else
'code should here
end if
```

thanks in advance on any helps

Comment: I think you should also include how you declared `VALUE1` and `VALUE2`, and how you set their values.

Comment: declared VALUE1 and VALUE2 already added

Comment: Please don't tag your question with VB.NET if it has nothing to do with VB.NET.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thanks for your correction

Comment: Not working is not the correct way to specify your problem. Also, I am not able to understand your problem correctly. Please specify your problem with example. Example, VALUE1 = 1 and VALUE2 = 0 , the 'IF' condition should get executed

Comment: Late reply. Sorry. You still didn't showed us how you declared VALUE1 and VALUE2. In that way we can see what is the datatype used for the said variables. Are they `strings`? If so, I would say that you are using the wrong datatype in your scenario. And as per your question, I think you should use `Val(VALUE1) = 0 or Val(VALUE2) = 0`, although I don't encourage you to use `Strings` in your case. You should learn that there is a proper usage for every datatype.

Comment: VALUE1 = "0" and VALUE2 = "0" above is a declaration. in my example, lets say it has values from database, VALUE1= "1" and  VALUE2= "0". i expect with its values where VALUE1 has "1" the condition will enable go to the code should before else section.

Comment: @SRR It will.  But you need some actual code in there, not just a comment or the whole block will be stepped over.  Try adding in a `MsgBox` to each branch and check what gets executed.

Comment: @Dave: there is no `MsgBox` function available in asp-classic.

Comment: @Martha Ok, that was just to illustrate the point - there's nothing in either branch of the `If` statement to execute, so the code will appear to do nothing anyway and step right over the comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood with your multiple statements is if only VALUE1 and VALUE2 **both** are equal to **zero(0)** then If condition should be executed, otherwise Else condition should be executed

```
if (Cint(VALUE1) = 0) AND (Cint(VALUE2) = 0) then 'please note the operator AND
'code should here
else
'code should here
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim rsY, sql, value1, value2
 sql = "SELECT COUNT(VALUE1) AS VALUE1, COUNT(VALUE2) AS VALUE2 FROM DUAL"
 SET rsY = cn.execute (sql)
 value1= 1 'Without ""
 value2= 0

IF Not rsY.EOF Then 
   value1= rsY("VALUE1") 
   value2= rsY("VALUE2")
End If 
Set rsY = nothing


If (Cint(value1) = 0) AND (Cint(value2) = 0) Then 'If Both equals zero 
  Response.Write("Enter in if condition");
Else 'If any of the values ​​are different from zero
  Response.Write("Enter in else condition");
End If
```